# How to iterate dictionaries and save in to the database in python2.7?

Tags: django, python-2.7

This is my dictionary

```
{u'krishna': [u'vijayawada', u'gudivada', u'avanigada']}
```

I want to iterate items and save in the database,my Models is

```
class Example(models.Model):
  district = models.CharField(max_length=50,**optional)
  taluk = models.CharField(max_length=20,**optional)
```

It should save as:

```
 -----------------------------
 |district   |         taluk  | 
 |-----------|--------------- | 
 |krishna    | vijayawada     |           
 |-----------|----------------|
 |krishna    | gudivada       |
 |----------------------------|         
 |krishna    | avanigada      |
 ------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:-

```
for districtName in places.keys():
    for talukName in places[districtName]:
        print districtName,talukName #Try to print it
        addData = Example.objects.create(district=districtName,taluk=talukName)
        addData.save()
```

Comment: sorry not working, taluk is saving the individual character of values,for example, vijayawada  should store in taluk but it is storing as v in one row ,i in second row i.e; storing the characters row  by row

Comment: try to run updated one now and see what it's printing.

Comment: yes in python 3 ,its working but i want based on python 2.7 only

Comment: @praveenjp If you think my answer is useful for you then you should accept and up vote it, check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I am new to stack over flow,i have less than 15 reputations,so it will be not affected

Comment: It's fine Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
form models import Example

places = {u'krishna': [u'vijayawada', u'gudivada', u'avanigada']}

for district in places:
    for taluk in district:
        e = Example(district=district, taluk=taluk)
        e.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in dict:
    for value in dict[key]:
         example = Example()
         example.district = key
         example.taluk = value
         example.save()
```