# How to remove QueryDict from Dictionary in python2.7?

Tags: django, python-2.7

This is my dictionary

```
<QueryDict: {u'karnataka': [u'bangalore', u'tumkur']}>
```

I want to remove the QueryDict and i want as

```
{u'karnataka': [u'bangalore', u'tumkur']}
```

Comment: It isn't a dictionary, it *is* a QueryDict... [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: ya i want to remove the "queydict", i want to iterate the dictionary

Comment: Just iterate over the query dict... again, what is the exact issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Selcuk I also want the unicode for that dictionary, i just want to remove QueryDict

Comment: @Sayse,if i am trying to iterate then i am facing problem,iteration is not perfect,if it is in this way it is working just see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42197322/how-to-iterate-dictionaries-and-save-in-to-the-database-in-python2-7/42198288?noredirect=1#comment71559816_42198288

Comment: That question is equally as unclear as this one is, [ask]

Answer (score -2):

```
from django.utils import six

fields = dict(six.iterlists(request.POST))
print fields
```

I sorted out this works perfectly